# problema con cookie y tabla usuarios mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

Hola gente estoy haciendo la parte de "Mantener la sesión iniciada" de la siguiente forma: se crean dos cookies, una con el idusuario y la otra con una serie de números aleatorios (los cuales son un campo de la tabla usuario), el problema que tengo es que cuando la cookie de la serie de números me la setea,lo hace con un valor que ya no está en la tabla, osea es que la cookie siempre me guarda el valor anterior que estaba en la tabla y nunca el actual.. entonces nunca me coinciden y por ende no me funciona

> Ejemplo del PROBLEMA: valor actual de cookie_login en la tabla usuarios es 565, luego el usuario si loguea con la opción de "mantener sesión iniciada" este valor se actualiza a otro.. por ej 124, pero la cookie se queda con el valor 565 y no se porque hace eso..
>   creería que es por la cookie esta en la lado del cliente y entonces nunca está sincronizada en tiempo real con el servidor.. pero como lo puedo solucionar??

Adjunto el código:

```
 if($a->ConectarUser($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'])==1)
    {
        echo "Se ha logueado correctamente";
        if ($_POST["recordame"]=="1") //es que pidió memorizar el usuario
        {
        //busco el id del usuario que hizo Esto , lo saco del metodo ConectarUser, el cual ya creò una sesion con el idusuario
        $iduser=intval($_SESSION["idUsuario"]);
  //1) creo una marca aleatoria en el registro de este usuario
  //alimentamos el generador de aleatorios
  mt_srand (time());
  //generamos un número aleatorio
  $numero_aleatorio = mt_rand(1000000,999999999);
  //2) meto la marca aleatoria en la tabla de usuario
  //3) ahora meto una cookie en el ordenador del usuario con el identificador del usuario y la cookie aleatoria
  setcookie("idusuario", $iduser , time()+(60*60*24*365));
  setcookie("marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw", $numero_aleatorio, time()+(60*60*24*365));

        $a->cargar_cookie_user($numero_aleatorio,$iduser);
  echo $_COOKIE['idusuario'];
        echo $_COOKIE['marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw'];
 }
    header('Location: ../main.php');
 }
```

saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema es el desconocimiento del funcionamiento de las cookies en general y de la variable global $_COOKIE.

**Qué es una cookie?**

Una cookie está formada por una clave que le da nombre y un valor asociado, que se puede crear, modificar o borrar tanto en el cliente como en el servidor y que una vez creada se envía en cada petición HTTP, de cada archivo, como parámetro de este protocolo. El nombre de cookies se deriva del término informático magic cookie, que define a la información que se envía y se devuelve igual en cada petición.

**Cómo funciona una cookie?**

El cliente con su navegador hace una petición al servidor:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

El servidor contesta:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=value
(content of page)
```

El navegador setea la cookie con name=value. Si nada cambia, el navegador envia otra petición:

```
GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
Cookie: name=value
Accept: */*
```

Ahora, como modifico una cookie? Si modificas la cookie con js, el cambio se hace en el cliente, por ejemplo name=ger, la proxima pagina que pidas dirá

```
GET /otrapage.html HTTP/1.1
Cookie: name=ger
Accept: */*
```

Si en cambio el que cambia el valor es PHP (o cualquier lenguaje en el servidor) y pone name=fer, la respuesta dirá

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=fer
(content of page)
```

**Entonces, cuál es el problema?**

En tu código, el cliente envia una cookie, php lee la cookie, la inserta en la variable global $_COOKIE['idusuario'], por lo tanto vale 565. en tu script (del lado de servidor obvio) vos haces

```
$iduser = 124;
setcookie("idusuario", $iduser , time()+(60*60*24*365));
```

que si lees la definición te dice: "setcookie() define una cookie para ser enviada junto con el resto de las cabeceras de HTTP." esto quiere decir que el servidor ahora esta listo para responder con

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: idusuario=124
(content of page)
```

Peeeero, $_COOKIE sigue con el valor que tenia antes, que es la cabecera del header que recibió antes, por lo tanto su valor no cambio. luego haces

```
 header('Location: ../main.php');
```

si en la primera linea de main.php pones echo $_COOKIE['idusuario']; te va a dar 124, porque la pagina donde estabas (llamemosle login.php) respondio con la cabecera de set-cookie y location, el navegador del cliente guardo al cookie y dijo

```
GET /main.php HTTP/1.1
Cookie: idusuario=124
Accept: */*
```

**Otras cosas a tener en cuenta**

Todo esto se produce en los headers, es decir si ahces un echo o algo que obligue a la pagina a renderizarse, no vas a poder modificar las cookies y vas a recibir un warning.

Espero haya quedado claro. saludos!

Comment: te entendí hasta una parte jaja  , no me quedò bien claro lo del refresh osea en que parte tengo que refrescar la web para que se tome la nueva cookie?? porque yo seteo la cookic y luego se redirige a la pagina main.php  esto no implicaria que tome la nueva cookie?? no comprendo bien en que momento la puedo hacer variar

Comment: Claro, lee la cookie en main.php y va a tener el valor correcto, porque login.php setea la cookie, la envia al cliente pidiendo redireccion, el cliente la manda de vuelta a main.php y ahora esta disponible en $_COOKIE. avisa cualquier cosa y te ayudo

Comment: la duda que tengo es, esta bien la redireccion esa que hago?? yo en login.php seteo la cookie y redirecciono a main.php pero me toma el valor anterior.. no me doy cuenta donde tengo el problema jaja

Comment: El valor "anterior" esta en login.php,hace un echo en main y vas a ver q tiene el valor correcto. Si es asi, te pediria q marques mi respuesta correcta, es lo mas largo q escribi en stackoverflow jeje

Comment: recien probé y no me imprime nada en main no se porque u.u

Comment: añadio una cosa.. en localhost me anduvo pero en el servidor no me anda ninguna cookie  . como puede ser??

Comment: Yo te tiro un par de datos y si no funciona te diria que hagas otra pregunta, porque es un problema diferente. proba lo uqe dicen aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121553/cookies-not-working-on-my-website-but-work-on-localhost  y lo que dicen aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain  puede que solo sea qu ea la cookie le falte el "path", es decir, setcookie("idusuario", $iduser , time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');

Comment: me anduvo, era el tema del path.. pero las sesiones no me las crea.. osea si yo me logueo y cierro el navegador, al volverlo abrir las cookies coinciden y necesito setear las variables $_SESSION correspondientes pero no me anda no se porque (uso session_start() )

Comment: Esa es, aún, otra pregunta diferente :) mostra el codigo en otra pregunta y lo vemos.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw", $numero_aleatorio, time()+(60*60*24*365));
```

Crea la cookie en el browser

```
  echo $_COOKIE['idusuario'];
```

no lee la cookie que acabas de enviar, lee de un array con el estado de las cookies **en el momento en que se inició el script** ( antes de que la cambies )

pero puedes usar $numero_aleatorio sin problema
o hacer un redirect a otra página y esa ya tendrá la cookie nueva

```
header( 'Location: /login_ok.php' );
```